# TFS2015 Build + SonarQube + ALL C# Rules = Build Failure

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015, msbuild, tfs-2015

I have a build, which was being executed and publishing to SonarQube correctly when my rule set for C# was the default one. Then I created a new rule set with all C# roles and set it in the quality profiles for that specific project, then my build started to get this error:

*Unable to read Code Analysis output report. Make sure that the directory is writable (default is the project output directory).
Process 'msbuild.exe' exited with code '1'.*

Comment: Do you mean Microsoft All Rules? (I don't find All C# Rules) Based on my test with TFS 2015 build+SonarQube 6.0+Microsoft All Rules, it builds fine and the result is updated to SonarQube server. Share your build log and project on the OneDrive, I will check it.

Comment: Do you solve this issue? If not, you can share build log and sample project on the OneDrive.

Comment: I found that some issues occur when a comma is in the file name. Like: File(T,Class).cs  ... renaming it solves the issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Refer to these ways to solve the issue:

1. Reduce the path length to be below 260 characters. As the old Windows API imposes a restriction of the total length a file name is allowed to be.
2. Remove the  `<CodeAnalysisLogFile>bin\Release\MyProjectA.exe.CodeAnalysisLog.xml</CodeAnalysisLogFile>`
   lines from the .csproj file
3. Clean the Team Build workspace to ensure that an older version of this file isn't causing any issues. (Delete files in target workspace manually or clean repository before build (open build definition=>Repository, select false for Clean option))

More information, you can refer to [this](http://blog.jessehouwing.nl/2012/01/solving-msbuild-error-unable-to-read.html) article.

Comment: After i clean the workspace and folders related, and then restarted the sonarserver it worked.